# How to enable KeystoneJS editor for logged in Users?

Tags: keystonejs

Is it possible to enable the KeystoneJS editor also for logged in users? Just changing the check in the `generator-keystone` default layout from `if user && user.canAccessKeystone` to `if user` is not enough.

I also added the `wysiwyg` class to the textarea where I want to editor to appear.

Comment: What do you mean by the "KeystoneJS editor"?

Comment: I mean the wysiwyg editor in the admin area of keystone. Since Its already available, I also want to use it outside the admin area.